# Reset Application VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reset

I'm developing a game and I'm there a lot of things that change after a few minutes, so I created a New Game button where I use Application.Restart() to clean everything and get a new fresh game, but the problem is that this exits the game and starts a new one. What I want to do is to restart a game, but without the players noticing that the game exits. How do I do this?

best regards, joao.

Comment: How would you answer this question if someone asked you?  It's far too broad.  It all depends how your code is architected.  Basically, you need to design your code in a way that each game is encapsulated in a single object or form, so you can create a new one when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement Start(), Stop() and Restart() methods on your main game controller class.  The Restart() method should reset the values of all variables, states, players, scores etc and reset the game board / environment and reset the game to it's original state.  Application.Restart() will always be noticable unfortunately.

Comment: Is there anyway to clean everything automaticly just by closing the game form & returning to the main menu?

Comment: It depends how you've implemented your forms.  If you have a MainMenuForm which is your application start form, the use GameForm.ShowDialog() while the game is running, then you can simply close the GameForm calling this.Close() from the GameForm.  Make sure you kill any background threads too, otherwise your form may not dispose completely.